# In ArcGIS or QGIS is it possible to add timestamps to geotiffs from a CSV file containing the timestamps?

Tags: arcgis, qgis, arcmap

I have about 400 geotiffs consisting of satellite data obtained on different dates. I would like to make an animated time series from these data using GIS (either in ArcGIS or QGIS), Python or R. The issue I am having with the GIS approach is that the geotiffs do not have a 'date' field and so I cannot do this directly. However, I have a CSV file containing the geotiff file names in one column and the date for each geotiff in another. So my question is: **Is it possible to populate the geotiffs with the time information contained in the CSV file**? Furthermore, each of my geotiff filenames contain the date within them (in format YYYY-mm-dd), i.e. *'XYZ_2000-01-01.tif'*.

So far I have tried using the Time Manager plugin in QGIS, with which I attempted to extract the date for each geotiff from the filename (see screenshot below). This was unsuccessful (*Error = Could not find a suitable time format or date*). I managed to create an animated time series for the data in R but I couldn't add a basemap, so the geographical context was lost.

[image: Attempt to extract geotiff date using Time Manager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying your date start wrongly and I think you probably want to add them as rasters not layers. Your date starts at a long way past 0 - 50 something. So I would rename all your files to put the date at the start to save counting all the way to the end.

My setup looks like (in QGIS Pi):

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ian Turton, I'll give this a go and let you know how it goes!

Comment: this seems to be working for far, but do you know if there is a way to do it as a batch process? I have around 400 rasters so manually doing this for each one isn't feasible, annoyingly!

Comment: I'm not sure but you could look at the code and see if it is an easy fix